# Find k such that f(x) is increasing.

Tags: calculus

My question is:
Find $k\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=x^3+kx^2+3x+1$ is increasing.

My solution is:
It must be $f'(x)=3x^2+2kx+3\geq 0$. I find the discriminant which is $d=4k^2-4\cdot3\cdot 3=4k^2-36\geq 0.$

Then I get that $-3\leq k\leq3.$ This is wrong. I cannot see what I have done wrong.

Comment: When the discriminant is positive then you have $2$ solutions, which means that your quadratic (which is the derivative) have at least two places where it changes signs which means...

Comment: You may also complete the square (in reference to the derivative). Then you never have to worry about the discriminant.

Comment: Why are you saying this is wrong?

Comment: because that is wrong: discriminant must be negative or rather non positive, if zero, the function will have stationary point, but still be increasing

Comment: The result $-3\leq k \leq 3$ corresponds to non positive discriminants. Indeed it doesn't correspond to the "$d\geq 0$" statement just before.

Comment: ah right, so this is the question why it's wrong

Comment: So d should be less and equal to 0. This means k is in (-infty,-3] and [3,infty). But even this is wrong and does not make sense when I draw the graph. The graph is increasinf for all values of k from -infty til infty.

Comment: no, your answer seem to be right, you just made mistake when saying d is non-negative, must say d is non-positive, but the answer is right, why you say it's wrong?

Comment: Because for all different values of k the graph is increasing. Therefore my solution is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you don't know where to zoom in to see with enough precision in the graph? Plots can be of too bad resolution and zoomed into wrong places.

Comment: So what is the right answer? I am still confused? The problem in that if I let k=0, the graph is increasing. For k=-6, k=-1, k=3, k=5 the graph is increasing. How can it be true?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3+%2B4x%5E2%2B+3x+%2B+1+

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I was actually not zooming correct. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f$ to increase for all $x$ we need $f' \ge 0$ for all $x$. 
$f' = 3x^2 + 2kx + 3 = ax^2 + bx + c$, we know this is a upward facing parabola ($a > 0$), and so if the vertex lies on or above the x-axis, we are okay.

The vertex has $x$-coordinate $-b/2a = -k/3$ and has y-cooridnate $f'(-b/2a = -k/3) = k^2/3 - 2k^2/3 + 3 = 3 - k^2/3$ which we require to be larger than or equal to zero.

This occurs if $|k| \le 3$. So it seems like your answer is correct?

Comment: K square over 9?

Comment: Thanks, edited :)