# Find k such that the function is increasing

Tags: calculus

I want to find $k$ so that the function $f(x)=2x+1+k \sin(x)$ is increasing.
I get $f'(x)=2+k\cos(x).$ Then how should I show that $f'$ is positive.

Comment: It's $f'(x)=2+k\cos x$.

Comment: Take what you have learned from your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424949/find-k-such-that-fx-is-increasing) and show some of your thoughts.  Doing your homework is just extra practice for us, but we can assure you that you would get more out of it if you tried it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x) = 2 + k \cos(x) \ge 0$ $\forall$ $x$, since $|\cos(x)| \le 1$ then $f'(x) \ge 2 - |k|$. So for $f' \ge 0$ we need $|k| \le 2$.

Comment: We have $\cos x \in [-1,1]$, so your solution is incomplete.  For example, $k=-10$ based on your solution should satisfy $f'>0\ \forall x$, but it does not.

Comment: Of course you are correct, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $|\cos(x)| \le 1$ for all real values of $x$. In order to have $f'(x)=2+k\cos(x)> 0$ for every $x$, we need $|k|<2$. This gives us $f'(x)=2+k\cos(x)\ge 2-|k|>2-2=0$.